# passing parameters in a query - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

The query "**select * from (select * from table1 where upper(column1) like upper('abc%') and column2 is null) where upper(column3) like upper('abcde%') and rownum <= 10;**" was returning 2 rows in DB. But while using the same query in my code, it is not fetching any value.

```
private static final String SQL = "select * from "+
          "(select * from table1 where upper(column1) like upper(:minimzedSearchString) and column2 is null) "+
          "where upper(column4) like upper(:searchString) "+
          "and rownum <= :max";

inside a method,

List<Table1> list = (List<Table1>) currentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(SQL)
                .setParameter("minimzedSearchString",minimzedSearchString)
                .setParameter("searchString", s)
                .setParameter("max", max)
                .list();
```

Here list is empty. Please let me know if I'm doing some error here.

Comment: what values do you pass for the parameters? Maybe provide an example of input and output

Comment: @Lino, for minimizedSearchString and searchString , I'm passing a string and for max, I'm passing int value